# Is there any way to override the titleView fading in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios7, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to figure out how to override the iOS 7 fading animation on my UINavigationBar's titleView when transitioning to a new view, but I can't seem to get it to change. Basically, I just want to stop the fading animation and keep the titleView's alpha at 1.0, but no matter what I try it always seems to fade out then back in. I'm using a custom transition using the new UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, which leaves the navigation bar there while the view transitions (which is desired), but still fades. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
-Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do that. Title views aren't shared from one view controller to the next across the transition. The old title view is replaced with the new one, using a cross-fade, even if the titles have the same text. To prevent fading, you'd need to write your own navigation controller / navigation bar / navigation item classes.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for the response!